# How to include config files in Ant WAR task?

Tags: java, ant, war, build.xml

I have a Java web app and am using Ant to produce the WAR file for me. Here is my project structure:

```
src/main/java/
    <Java sources>
src/main/config/
    web.xml
    mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    pages/
        home.jsp
        cool.jsp
lib/main/
    <Libs>
gen/
    bin/
    dist/
```

I need a Java WAR produced with the following directory structure:

```
myapp.war/
    META-INF/
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        mvc-dispatcher.xml
        pages/
            home.jsp
            cool.jsp
        classes/
            <Compiled Java binaries>
        lib/
            <All lib JARS>
```

Here is my WAR task:

```
<target name="package" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="gen/dist/myapp.war" webxml="src/main/config/web.xml"
            basedir="gen/bin"
            includes="src/main/config">
        <classes dir="gen/bin" />
        <lib dir="lib/main" />
    </war>
</target>
```

When I run this target, it produces a WAR with the following structure:

```
myapp.war/
    META-INF/
    WEB-INF/
        web.xml
        classes/
            <Compiled Java binaries>
        lib/
            <All lib JARS>
```

Notice how `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and the entire `pages` directory is missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here: basedir="gen/bin",  this is root directory to take data

Comment: Thanks @LeosLiterak (+1) but this only partially works. I changes basedir="gen/bin" to basedir="src/main/config". It places my config files in the WAR at the same level as `WEB-INF` and `META-INF`. But I need them **inside** `WEB-INF`. For example, right now my WAR has `pages` in the same dir as `WEB-INF`, but I need it at `WEB-INF/pages`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeking for `webinf` element. See [ant manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) for more details.

> The nested webinf element specifies a FileSet. All files included in
>   this fileset will end up in the WEB-INF directory of the war file. If
>   this fileset includes a file named web.xml, the file is ignored and
>   you will get a warning.

Use following snippet that combines several use cases.

```
<war destfile="${build.dir}/${ant.project.name}_${version}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <webinf dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF">
        <exclude name="web.xml"/>
        <exclude name="classes/**"/>
        <exclude name="lib/**"/>
        <exclude name="flex/services-config.xml"/>
    </webinf>
    <lib dir="${war.web-inf.dir}/lib"/>
    <lib file="${build.dir}/*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
        <include name="img/*"/>
    </fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the `zip` ant task instead of `war`. You can copy all classes/libraries in a folder in the structure you require and zip the content into a .war file. This deploys as a war without any issues as long as web.xml is in the right place in the war.